# Yii2 Html::dropDownList and Html::activeDropDownList trade-off

Tags: php, yii2

In Yii2, using `Html::activeDropDownList`, I can submit data in a form like the following:

```
 <?= Html::activeDropDownList($model, 'category', ArrayHelper::map($categories, 'id', 'name'), [
       'multiple' => 'multiple',
       'class' => 'multiselect',
 ]) ?>
```

Is there a way to specify pre-selected categories in the above?
I know it can be done using `Html::dropDownLost` like the following:

```
<?= Html::dropDownList('category', [1, 3, 5], ArrayHelper::map($categories, 'id', 'name'), [
     'multiple' => 'multiple',
     'class' => 'multiselect',
]) ?>
```

But there is a trade-off! There is no place to indicate that this is some data attached to a certain model to submit as there was using `Html::activeDropDownList`.

One of the solution I found was to use `ActiveForm` like the following:

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'category')
      ->dropDownList('category', [1, 3, 5], ArrayHelper::map($categories, 'id', 'name')
]) ?>
```

The problem I have with that last option is that I am not able to specify the html options such as 'multiple' and css such as 'class'.

Any help on being able to use drop down list with the ability to specify that the list be multiselect and have pre-selected values? Also if someone directed me to a resource where I can read about when and where to choose `activeDropDownList` or `dropDownList`, I would really appreciate that.

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**@scaisEdge**'s answer is correct but there is another option you may try:

```
<?php 
$model->category = [1,3,5]; //pre-selected values list
echo $form->field($model, 'category')
    ->dropDownList(ArrayHelper::map($categories, 'id', 'name'), 
        [
            'multiple' => 'multiple',
            'class' => 'YOUR_CLASS'
        ]
) ?>
```

This code is also valid and tested.
Happy coding :)

Comment: This is clean and what I wanted.. thanks @ankitraturi

Answer (score 8):

I think you can try with $options and [tag attribute](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-helpers-basehtml.html#renderTagAttributes%28%29-detail)  like suggested [in doc](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-helpers-basehtml.html#activeDropDownList%28%29-detail)

```
<?= Html::dropDownList('category', [1, 3, 5], ArrayHelper::map($categories, 'id', 'name'), [
   'multiple' => 'multiple',
   'options' => [
        'value1' => ['disabled' => true, 'class' => 'yourClass', 'style'=> 'yourStyle', .... ],
        'value2' => ['label' => 'value 2'],
    ];
]) ?>
```

Comment: The above snippet does what I wanted except one thing: it does not attach data to my model. @ankitraturi's answer is the right one! Thanks for your time though!